# Wait in nested observables

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I'm new to Observables; I have to convert a nested for loop with Observables and, when a condition is meet, wait for a certain amount of time.
I was able to convert the for-loop with Observables, but I don't reach to achieve the "pause" of the flow of 5 seconds after the globalCounter variable value is set to 5.
How to do it?
Thanks.

```
import { map, Observable, Subject } from "rxjs";

const array1 = ["Alfa", "Beta", "Gamma"];
const array2 = ["Laura", "Valentina", "Cristina"];
const array3 = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"];

const mySubject = new Subject<number>();
let globalCounter = 0;

const myObservable1$ = new Observable<string>((observer1) => {
  array1.map((u) => {
    observer1.next(u);
  });
});

const pipeline1 = myObservable1$
  .pipe(
    map(async (value1) => {
      const return2 = await fObservable2(value1);
      return2.subscribe({});
    })
  )
  .subscribe();

async function fObservable2(value1: string) {
  return new Observable<string>((observer2) => {
    array2.map(async (d) => {
      const valueToPassTofObservable3 = value1 + " --- " + d;
      const return3 = await fObservable3(valueToPassTofObservable3);
      return3.subscribe({
        next: async (value3) => {
          console.log(
            `OBSERVABLE2 - value3: ${value3} - globalCounter: ${globalCounter}`
          );
        },
      });
    });
  });
}


async function fObservable3(value2: string) {
  let toBeReturn3;
  if (globalCounter === 5) {
    await sleep();
  }
  return new Observable<string>((observer3) => {
    array3.forEach((t) => {
      toBeReturn3 = t + " --- " + value2;
      observer3.next(toBeReturn3);
      mySubject.next(globalCounter++);
    });
  });


}

function sleep() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setInterval(() => {
      globalCounter = 0;
      resolve(true);
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are mixing up observables and promises.

**Observables**

- An observable is an object that you can subscribe to. Subscribing means that some callback is executed when a value is received from that observable. An observable can send multiple values, which means the callback is executed multiple  times.
- Observables can be piped. Piping means that you somehow create a new observable from one or more observables. For example, you can combine observables, wait for some other observable before subscribing to another one, etc. The possibilities are endless
- Observables are not the same thing as promises (though you can convert it into a Promise). Therefore, the `async / await` syntax does not work (nor does it make sense, because an observable can emit multiple values)

**How to solve your problem**

Use the correct pipes. You can find them using https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree.

But I will help you a little. If I understood your code correctly, you want to:

- Loop over `array1`
- For every element in `array1`, loop over `array2`
- For every element in `array2`, loop over `array3`
- if the function `fObservable3` is executed for the 5'th time, wait for 5 seconds.

You can achieve that with

```
class SomeClass {
  private loopedElementsCounter = 0;
  
  constructor(){
    from(array1).pipe(
      concatMap(array1El => loopOverSecondArray(array1El))
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
  }

  private loopOverSecondArray(array1El): Observable<any> {
    return from(array2).pipe(
      concatMap(array2El => loopOverThirdArray(array1El, array2El))
    )
  }

  private loopOverThirdArray(array1El, array2El): Observable<any> {
    return from(array3).pipe(
      concatMap(array3El =>  sleepIfNecessary(array1El, array2El, array3El))
    )
  }

  private sleepIfNecessary(array1El, array2El, array3El): Observable<any> {
    const obs = of('construct your string from array1El, array2El, array3El here')
    this.loopedElementsCounter += 1;
    if (this.loopedElementsCounter !== 5) return obs;
    return obs.pipe(delay(5000))
  }
}
```

Note that `concatMap` and `delay` are pipes, which can be found on the RxJS website. `of` and `from` are functions to easily construct observables, which can also be found on the RxJS website.

Answer (score 0):

Make the condition into an observable as well. Then you can use `takeUntil` to wait for that observable to complete. If your condition does not complete you can use a `switchMap`. This lets you swap your current `observable` with another one. Therefore the next step is "paused" until a new value of that observable is emitted.

Also I recommend to add a `$` after the name of on observable to make it very clear.

```js
let globalCounter$ = new BehaviousSubject(0);

// instead of counter +1 you can use the following to increment the counter
this.globalCounter$.next(this.globalCounter.value + 1);

// where you want to wait
// .pipe(filter(counter => counter < 5)) creates a new observable that only emits values when the counter >= 5
takeUntil(
  this.globalCounter$.pipe(filter(counter => counter < 5))
})
```